# pandas count words in a dataframe with multiplier value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe with tweets and I have a column that says how many times those tweets were retweeted. When I count the words I want to multiply them by the number of times they were retweeted.

For example, for this table, I want to count apple and banana 2 times but pineapple 4 times. So, in overall I want to count apple 6 times and banana 2 times.

```
tweet            retweet
-------------------------
apple banana       2
pineapple apple    4
```

If I only wanted to count the tweets, I could do

```
tweet_text = df['tweet'].str.cat(sep=' ')
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(tweet_text)
most_common = pd.DataFrame(nltk.ngrams(tokens, 1)).value_counts().to_frame()
```

If I wanted bigrams, I could simply do:

```
most_common = pd.DataFrame(nltk.ngrams(tokens, 2)).value_counts().to_frame()
```

But how do take retweets into consideration?

Comment: I don't fully follow. Do you want to count the number of times a word appears in a tweet?

Comment: Yes, but not only in a single tweet. I want to count the number of times a word occurs in combination of all tweets. I have edited the example to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I try to solve it with a dictionary:

```
myDict = {}
tweets = pd.DataFrame({'tweet': ['apple bannana', 'pineapple', 'apple strawberry'],
                       'retweet': [2,4,3]})
    for idx, row in tweets.iterrows():
        for i in row['tweet'].split(" "):
            if i in myDict:
                myDict[i] = myDict[i] + row["retweet"]
            else:
                myDict[i] = row["retweet"]
    print(myDict)
```

Output would now be `{'apple': 5, 'bannana': 2, 'pineapple': 4, 'strawberry': 3}` Hopefully i understood the problem right.
Maybe it's not the most efficient way. Another attempt would be to create a dataframe with each word of every tweet as row ad than use groupby().sum().

**Update on bigrams**
First here maybe a another posibilty to count the single words.

```
tweets = pd.DataFrame({'tweet': ['apple bannana', 'pineapple', 'apple strawberry'],
                       'retweet': [2,4,3]})
unigrams = (
        tweets['tweet'].str.lower()
            .str.replace(r'[^a-z\s]', '')
            .str.split(expand=True)
            )
unigramDF = pd.DataFrame(unigrams)
unigramDF['retweet'] = tweets['retweet']

unigramDF = pd.melt(unigramDF, id_vars='retweet').drop(['variable'], axis=1).dropna().groupby(['value']).sum()
print(unigramDF)
```

i used some code from here (for the credits): [Generate N-Grams from strings with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49147128/generate-n-grams-from-strings-with-pandas)

Now the bigrams:

```
bigrams = []
for idx, row in tweets.iterrows():
    unigrams = (
        row['tweet'].lower().replace(r'[^a-z\s]', '').split((' '))
    )
    for i in range(0,len(unigrams)-1):
        bigrams.append([unigrams[i] + ' ' + unigrams[i+1], row['retweet']])
bigramDF = pd.DataFrame(bigrams, columns=['bigram', 'retweet'])
bigramDF.groupby(['bigram']).sum()
print(bigramDF)
```

Now With these two dataframes it should not be not too difficulty to calculate the probabilities.

Comment: Thank you, but I also want to count bigrams. It would not be possible with this method, no?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I needed to count the occurrence of words in a message. If you want to count word occurrence in a single tweet (one cell of your dataframe) then this will work

```
def word_frequency(str):
    counts = dict()
    words = str.split()

    for word in words:
        if word in counts:
            counts[word] += 1
        else:
            counts[word] = 1
    return counts
```

This will return a dictionary with the words as keys and their counts as values and you could apply this to your tweets column.

Then you could use this to understand that data

```
##lists for storing output of words and associated counts
words = []
occurrence = []

##add words and counts to above lists
for comment in comments:
    for key in word_frequency(comment).keys():
        words.append(key)
    for value in word_frequency(comment).values():
        occurrence.append(value)

import pandas as pd
measure = pd.DataFrame({'word':words, 'occurrence':occurrence})
```

For bigrams (or any ngram), it could be done by changing the word_frequency function just a bit, then the rest of the code should still work

```
def ngrams_word_frequency(ngram):
    counts = dict()

    for gram in ngram:
        words = ' '.join(word for word in gram)
        if words in counts:
            counts[words] += 1
        else:
            counts[words] = 1
    return counts
```

This requires that you give the ngrams_word_frequency function a list of lists, for my personal project, I created a ngrams function:

```
def ngrams(str, n):
    str = str.split()
    output = [str[i:i+n] for i in range(len(str)-n+1)]
    return output
```

Comment: Thank you, do you have an idea how I can extend this to count bigrams?

Comment: It's very possible. I edited the answer, so in reality, you could use the ngrams_word_frequency function for all of this since ngrams include unigrams.

Comment: wait, where does this consider number of retweets? Can you please provide a working example, maybe use same Table from question. Thank you

Comment: I think you have a good baseline here. But here's a tip, you would simply multiply the output of ```ngrams_word_frequency(ngram)``` by the appropriate retweet value.